# Отображение смс сообщений и их сортировка

Tags: android, sms

Всем привет. прошу помощи т.к. сам не смог разобраться.
Решил поиграться с СМС в андроиде- вытащить их, ченибудь сними поделать и т.д.
Вытащить получилось - на этом все. как делать сортировку напиример не пойму, или допустим, что бы по нажатию кнопки он искал определенный текст в сообщении, а потом выводил эти сообщения.

```
public class MessageBox extends Activity {

// GUI Widget
Button start;
TextView lblMsg, lblNo;
ListView lvMsg;
String number;
// Cursor Adapter
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messagebox);

    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    lvMsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);

 Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
   String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};
   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
   Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
          new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
           R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber});
   lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }

    });

}   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как вариант просто

```
  Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, "body='%text%", null, null);
```

`"body like '%text%"` найдет все сообщения где есть слово текст а вокруг него любые символы.
если где то не правильно написал меня поправят

Comment: спасибо большое, но знаки % не работают. Если я правильно понимаю правильная запись будет такая "body='%text%'" - без % находит слово и то если оно и составляет все смс. в тексте его находить не хочет

Comment: разобрался, нужно так "body like '%text%'"

Comment: @Alerx - только имейте ввиду, что это только *case sensitive* поиск, у SQLite есть родовая травма - *case insensitive* поиск работает только для ASCII набора.

Answer (score 1):

1. Для сортировки есть `ORDER BY` который надо вписать в ваш `query` последним параметром
2. Для поиска по SMS есть специальный недокументированный URI: `content://mms-sms/search` - поройтесь в исходниках :)

**Update**

В исходниках про поиск находится такое:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Uri u = Uri.parse(String.format(
            "content://mms-sms/searchSuggest?pattern=%s",
            selectionArgs[0]));
    Cursor c = getContext().getContentResolver().query(
            u,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    return new SuggestionsCursor(c, selectionArgs[0]);
}
```

Comment: а возможно ли к примеру подставить sum и count в запрос или надо будет создавать свою БД и оттуда селектить,

Comment: БД смс недоступна, доступ только через `ContentProvider`, так что обычные SQL запросы недоступны

Comment: по URI: content //mms-sms/search очень мало инфы

Comment: @Alerx у ты какой :) Сказано же что это недокументировано все - [Use the Source, Luke](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Use+the+Source%2C+Luke) - см. апдейт